# AWS Mobile Hub Sign In - How to find user sub on iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-mobilehub

I've incorporated the AWS Mobile Hub Cognito Sign-In as described in [Add AWS Mobile User SignIn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-sign-in.html) for iOS Swift and it's working as expected, however I can't seem to find a way to get the logged-in user's access_token, or more specifically, the user's sub from the decrypted access_token.

I was able to achieve this for Android by implementing a callback for AuthHandler, which calls a method called `onSuccess` and passes it an `AuthUserSession` object, which contains the auth_token.

From the docs, it appears there is something similar for iOS by implementing `AWSSignInDelegate`, but I can't figure out if the access_token is present or not in any of the delegate method's parameters. Maybe someone more familiar with it (or the debugger) can fill in the blanks?

```swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, AWSSignInDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        AWSSignInManager.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        return AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().interceptApplication(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    ...

    func onLogin(signInProvider: AWSSignInProvider, result: Any?, error: Error?) {
        // How to find the auth_token or sub from here?
    }
}
```

The `onLogin` method's `result` parameter seems like it's the most likely candidate for having what I need, but I can't figure out how to access it. If there's any other way of getting it, I'd be open to that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider` singleton object to get the Cognito User object and then you can go over the attributes to get the user-sub attribute.

```
AWSCognitoIdentityUser *user = [[[AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider sharedInstance] getUserPool] currentUser];

NSString *mySub;

[[user getDetails] continueWithBlock:^id _Nullable(AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityUserGetDetailsResponse *> * _Nonnull task) {
    if(!task.error){
        AWSCognitoIdentityUserGetDetailsResponse *response = task.result;
        NSArray<AWSCognitoIdentityProviderAttributeType*> *userAttributes = response.userAttributes;
        for (AWSCognitoIdentityProviderAttributeType *attr in self.userAttributes) {
            if ([attr.name isEqualToString:@"sub"]) {
                mySub = attr.value;
            }
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error fetching Cognito User Attributes: %@", task.error.localizedDescription);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Is there a way to get AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider to work in conjunction with the Google and Facebook SignIn Providers? When enabled, they create records in the User Pool, but they don't seem to have a reference to the AWSUserPool in their SDK classes.

Comment: You can have all three providers in your app. Are you trying to federate a user from facebook/google to userpool or link users? Can I know your use-case?

Comment: Trying to federate, I believe. I have the Mobile Hub configuration set up to enable the UserPool and Login with Facebook/Google buttons on the Sign In UI. My use case is that regardless of the login method (email, Google, FB), I want to use the 'sub' to uniquely identify the user to a non-AWS 3rd party API. It was fairly easy with the Android SDK, but iOS is proving more of a challenge.

Comment: Can you use Cognito Identity Id? You can federate UserPools/Facebook/Google with Cognito Identities and get a unique Cognito Identity Id for your user. Did you federate Facebook/Google into UserPools in Android?

Comment: I suppose it's possible to rewrite using a Cognito Identity ID instead. I had originally architected using the sub value because I'm also integrating with an Amazon Alexa skill which uses Cognito for Account Linking, so the token is readily available. In Android, the SDK's AuthBuilder exposes a callback which sends the AWS AuthUserSession object as a parameter which has the token readily available as well. In both cases, having Facebook and Google federated into the UserPool hasn't presented a problem with obtaining the AWS auth token, it's only iOS that seems to have a gap in the SDK.

Comment: Thank you, Duck Jones, for the feedback. I will share this with the team to see how we can fix the gap in iOS SDK.